# The proof of "Two rectangular matrices of the same dimension are equivalent $\iff$ they have the same rank"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

May someone clarify how did the author get the matrix $(37)$?
Doesn't $\mathbf {\mathit{A}e_i^*= \mathit{A}e_i \ (i=1, \dots, r)}$ which is unknown, so that the columns of $(37)$ should have been unknown?

Comment: The author denoted these $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{e}_i^\ast$ by $\mathbf{g}_i^\ast$ and used them as part of her basis for the codomain of the matrix, so they are now basis vectors. Keep in mind that the bases of the domain and of the codomain are being chosen **independently** here (the notion of "equivalent" allows changing both separately), so this is legitimate.

Comment: @darij Many thanks :), I got the idea. You are welcome to put this, if you like, in an answer and I'll accept it.